# Bookmarklet - is it possible to make one that has multiple independent paste operations (hardcoded values)?

Tags: bookmarklet

At my last job, I made a few bookmarklets with hardcoded values (company addresses/contact info by location, department contacts, etc) for FAQs so my team didn't have to look up the info and copy/paste it in every response, just click the appropriate bookmarklet.

I have a new challenge, and am asking whether this is possible with a bookmarklet. I have to frequently fill out the same web form, which includes multiple text fields but not always in the same order (extra fields may be interspersed with the fields that are always present). The html names of the fields seem to be dynamic (I don't think it is possible to just automate all entries).

I understand I could make a separate bookmarklet for every single field, but I'm wondering if a bookmarklet could be designed to hold 10 pieces of [hardcoded] info, and when I click the bookmarklet I then click on those primary 10 fields (in fixed order, one at a time) and have the info paste with each click (first click, auto-paste info #1 into the text field. second click, paste #2, etc).

Of course if I click the wrong field I'll have to reload the page and start again, but it would still be a better solution than having to type each field, or copy/paste from an open text file for each field.

/If/ this is possible, what are some of the search terms I should be using to find sample code that does this type of activity?

Thank you!

Use case:
Info #1: my name
Info #2: my employer
Info #3: our account code
Info #4: services type
etc.

Comment: So more broadly, I guess my question is twofold; (1) is there any type of on_click event I can use, and (2) can a bookmarklet pause while waiting for an event or is it run once/all at once.